# Mobile Safari (10.3.1) DateTime-Local "Enter a Valid Value" Error

Tags: ios, iphone, html, input, safari

I'm getting an error on the newer versions of iOS' Mobile Safari. This error didn't happen prior to version 10.3 of iOS. Can someone point me in the right direction on this?

Here's the raw HTML and attached are the inspected view and the view of the mobile device (iPhone 7).

[image: Inspector View]
[image: iPhone 7 View]

Comment: Apple **thinks different**... 3 years old bug still not fixed

Comment: Just stumbled upon the same myself. Is there a working alternative to datetime local for safari?

Comment: @SnorreHukkelås Not that I've found. I did submit the bug many, many years ago. Still nothing of a fix.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple solution!

IOS requires a value to be set on an input field with a type of "datetime-local".

Example: `<input type="datetime-local" value="2000-07-01T12:00" />`

That's it :)

I personally find it nice to set the default value to the users current local time. This has to be formatted in ISOTime without seconds, so the code for this might be something like:

```
// get the iso time string formatted for usage in an input['type="datetime-local"']
var tzoffset = (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000; //offset in milliseconds
var localISOTime = (new Date(Date.now() - tzoffset)).toISOString().slice(0,-1);
var localISOTimeWithoutSeconds = localISOTime.slice(0,16);

// select the "datetime-local" input to set the default value on
var dtlInput = document.querySelector('input[type="datetime-local"]');

// set it and forget it ;)
dtlInput.value = localISOTime.slice(0,16);
```

Comment: Except that doesn't work for my use case, where I want to make sure that the user has actually inspected and verified those fields to be correct. Pre-populating those fields for me would be wholly inappropriate.

Comment: (Marked as correct, as I can now submit the form. Although I hate that apple requires that, it's not your fault. Thank you for your help.)

Comment: Not working.  I even set both the value attribute and the .value to a date in this format and still no dice!  Argh!  I will update if I find a solution.

Answer (score 8):

This message is triggered by client-side validation.  If you are not using client-side validation then I found you can fix this issue by turning it off using the `novalidate` attribute as follows:

```
<form action="/myaction" method="POST" novalidate>
```

Answer (score 7):

For the whom still struggle with IOS datetime-local same as me.

This caused by IOS set datetime-local value in invalid format when value attribute/property not set or set with invalid one.

```
<input type='datetime-local' onChange='alert(event.target.value)'>
```

This will alert with 'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss' format such as 2018-12-25T12:00:00 which has unallowed string of seconds.

To bypass it, simply set the value with valid form.

```
const onChange = (event) => {
    event.target.value = event.target.value.substr(0, 16);
}
```

That`s it.

Answer (score 3):

Seems it's a bug in Safari, but you can skip it by using javascript to submit the form.

```
$("#new_apply_form").submit();
```

Comment: Thank god it's not just me! I'll submit this to the Safari Bug Team.

Comment: Submitted the bug FYI, here.
[Mobile Safari (10.3.1) DateTime-Local “Enter a Valid Value” Error](https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=32035489)

Comment: Also, the snippet just reloads the page over and over again. It needs to wait for the onClick event on the submit button otherwise it just continuously reloads the page.

Comment: Even in this form ... `$( "#hours" ).submit(function( event ) { return true; });` It still asks for a valid date. :/

Comment: Just FYI, we can't see that bug since it's private to your Apple ID.  Consider re-posting to Open Radar: http://www.openradar.me/

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in Safari. You should use JS to submit the form instead.

JS: `form.submit();`

Comment: That didn't work for me either, by adding the following to the submit button. `onClick="form.submit()"` All that does is reload the page, with no information submitted.

Answer (score 0):

`format('Y-m-d\TH:i')` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in iOS 15.4. On iOS 15.3.1, as soon as the user taps on the input, it automatically gets populated with the current date/time and the value will be something like this:

```
2022-03-18T13:30:45.123
```

So, unless the user changes the date and/or time to something else, submitting the form will cause a client-side validation error.

But on iOS 15.4, as soon as the user taps on the input, it still automatically gets populated with the current date/time, but now the value will be something like this:

```
2022-03-18T13:30
```